# UWP Converting a bitmapImage to be serialized with Json.

Tags: json, serialization, uwp, bitmapimage

I have a class (MyClass) that I serialize by using

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public BitmapImage image { get; set;}
}

private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _myClass;

private const string fileName = "myclass.json";

public DataSource()
{
 _myClass = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
}

public async Task<ObservableCollection<MyClass>> GetMyClass()
{
  await ensureDataLoaded();
  return _myClass;
}

private async Task ensureDataLoaded()
{
  if(_myClass.Count == 0;)
     await GetMyClassDataAsync();
}

private async Task GetMyClassDataAsync()
{
   if(_myClass.Count != 0)
       return;

var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<MyClass>));

try
 {
  using(var stream = away ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(fileName))
   {
   _myClass = (ObservableCollection<MyClass>) jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
   }
 }
catch
 {
  _myClass = new ObservableCollection<MyClasss>();
 }
}

public async void AddMyClass(MyClass myClass)
{
   _myClass.Add(myClass);
   await SaveMyClassDataAsync();
}

public async void DeleteMyClass(MyClass myClass)
{
   _myClass.Remove(myClass);
   await SaveMyClassDataAsync();
}

private async Task SaveMyClassDataAsync()
{
   var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<MyClass>));
   using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocatlFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName, 
   CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
 {
   jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, _myClass);
 }
}
```

When I add a bitmapImage to my class, it can't be serialized.

I've read about converting the bitmapImage to a string or to a byte array but I can't figure the code out.

Doest anyone know how to convert a bitmapImage to a format that can be serialized?

**Bonus**

After converting it to a format for json. How would I convert it back??

**MoreBonus**

If I have a list view of all my images that are linked to each MyClass object in XAML, is there anything special I have to do so that myClass holds an image & a serialized image so that I can save the image in json but also use the image to Bind from the MyClass to an image in XAML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[UWP\]Resize, compress and get base64 string from BitmapImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873292/uwpresize-compress-and-get-base64-string-from-bitmapimage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, BitmapImage is made to serve the UI as an image source. It's not a read/write object. So my suggestion would be to serialize/deserialize  the image data by itself (here in an array of bytes) and publish an ImageBitmap property using those data for the binding.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyClass
{
    private BitmapImage _Image;
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            if (ImageBytes == null)
                return null;
            if (_Image == null)
                _Image = new BitmapImage();
            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                stream.WriteAsync(ImageBytes.AsBuffer()).Completed = (i, j) => {
                    stream.Seek(0);
                    _Image.SetSource(stream);
                };
            }
            return _Image;
        }
    }
    [JsonProperty]
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
}
```

The story would have been a little different if you had an URI to the image ;)

Comment: *async-await* in setter?

Comment: You're probably trying to access the UI thread from another one. Try to use a dispatcher.

Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
    {
       XAMLimage.Source = _myClass.Image;
    });

Comment: I apologize, when I said setting the image. I meant setting the image to the _myClass.Image from the PickSingleFileAsync stream, I get the error while trying to set the image to _myClass.Image before I get to the XAMLimage.source

Comment: In my example, you don't set the Image property but the ImageBytes property, the one that is serialized/deserialized.

Comment: PickSingleFileAsync will get you a StorageFile, you will haveto get a byte array from there and set it to the ImageBytes property

Comment: Close this question and ask another one on Stackoverflow please

Comment: I've added the question "How do you assign a storage file to a ByteArray"

Comment: And if you think I answered this one, check it ;)